# SSRS groupings and sub totals

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

Working with SSRS and need to be able to accomplish subtotalling in the following manner:

I have a table, grouped on 'claim'; each claim has multiple lineitems.

I need to have each claim and the sub totals as claim1 amt, claim1 amt, subtotal for claim1.

Then Claim2 amt, claim2 amt, subtotal for Claim2

So the output would look like:

```
           CLAIM      Amt

           400-1     150.00
           400-2     100.00
```

Subtotal for Claim      400      250.00

```
          500-1      75.00
          500-2     100.00
```

Subtotal for Claim      500      175.00

and so forth.

It's the 'Subtotal" row in between i can't figure out.  I can't get it to show *after* the individual grouping in the table.  I need it to show after, and the end of the grouping, as it is now i insert the row with the summary of amt, and it sums correctly, but it shows up in between each row, as opposed to at the end of the grouping, then the next claim, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 'subtotal' group (parent to your claim group). Then you would add a group expression for said group to something like:

```
=LEFT(Fields!Claim.Value,3)
```

Or if it's not always three digits, then perhaps this will work:

```
=LEFT(Fields!Claim.Value, InStr(Fields!Claim.Value,"-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a tablix and grouping as below, you should achieve the result you desire:

[image: Claim LineItem Tablix]